# How to unrar multiple split files across different sub-folders

Tags: zip, rar

I have a directory that is like this :

/x/xxx/rar.00

I'm going manually inside each folder and then merging the files to a single file and then unzip it.

How can I automatically merge and then extract all the rar files inside /xxx with command-line or bash script  ?

Answer (score 2):

I've found a solution.

Just use `cd "path"` and then run `unrar e -r  *.rar`. And it will recursively extract all files in location